# codeigniter Query Grouping returning all results from my table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, query-builder

I'm using the CodeIgniter framework. I'm creating a search function for my companies CMS, the search has different inputs coming from a form. Is there a way to run query groups based on the `$_POST`input? I can run queries separate for example:

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_results($search_term='default')
{
    $cat = $_POST["col"];
    // Column Select:
    $col = 'id, dob, gender, app_date, tests_ordered, payment_method, cost, report_results, country';

    // Build the query.
    $database = $this->load->database('bookings_dev', TRUE)
        ->select($col)
        ->from('results')
                ->where($cat . ' ' . 'BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['sdate'])). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['edate'])).'"')
        ->order_by($_POST["col"]);

    // Execute the query.
    $query = $database->get();

    // Return the results.
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Works fine ad returns the correct records (for example all records within the selected date range, my issue is when I try and expand the query to take other options into account I either get all records from the db or none. I've tried changing the order of the LIKE and WHERE clauses, I've tried OR_LIKE, OR_WHERE etc. Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. I've read [CIs Query Builder Class Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) but m officially stuck. here is my model:

```
<?php
```

class Search_model extends CI_Model {

```
public function get_results($search_term='default')
{
    $cat = $_POST["col"];
    // Column Select:
    $col = 'id, dob, gender, app_date, tests_ordered, payment_method, cost, report_results, country';

    // Build the query.
    $database = $this->load->database('bookings_dev', TRUE)
        ->select($col)
        ->from('results')
            ->group_start()
                ->where($cat . ' ' . 'BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['sdate'])). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['edate'])).'"')
            ->group_end()
            ->or_group_start()
                ->or_like($_POST["col"], $_POST["terms"])
            ->group_end()
        ->order_by($_POST["col"]);

    // Execute the query.
    $query = $database->get();

    // Return the results.
    return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

What id like to achive is:
SELECT $cols FROM results WHERE condtion 1 has input OR condition 2 input OR condition 3 etc etc
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run query groups based on the `$_POST` input, but input is sent to controller, you should write the method with some paramaters and set it in controller. You cannot transfer data straight to model.
This is a reference.
https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Comment: I think we can still access `$_POST` in model, as its a super global variable. Ideally we should pass variables to the model method, but `$_POST` also works fine.

Comment: I don't know but CodeIgniter uses MVC pattern, we have to obey it. But your form sends data to controller, you cannot send to model.

Comment: Im affirmative on accessing $_POST from model. Its a superglobal variable which could be even accessed from helper or library as well. Although this practice is not a gud practice, we should be ideally using $this->input for parsing get and posts parameters. Its makes it easy to apply security settings to it.

Comment: Please try this:


`$this->db->where(array($cat . ' >' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['sdate'])), $cat . ' <' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['edate']))));`

Comment: Of course it will work. Check this out. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html